# Django + Angular deployment on Heroku

Tags: python, django, angularjs, heroku

I have a project consisting of the Django Rest Backend and AngularJS frontend. The project root directory contains two folders: `backend` and `frontend`, in the first one there is placed the whole Django app and in the second one the Angular frontend app.

Is it possible to deploy such a structure to Heroku in one subdomain. To be precise, I want to have urls like this:

`myapp.heroku.com` - which will load the whole Angular project frontend
`myapp.heroku.com/backend` - which will be the Rest API endpoint

How to deploy both apps on Heroku to obtain such a solution? Or maybe you have any other suggestions concerning the project structure and deployment?

Comment: I think its a question to heroku itself (ask their support), not for stackoverflow.

Comment: have you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this project.

https://github.com/djng/djng

They've used a DjangoREST backend and a Angular Front end.
Instead of letting heroku autodetect the app environment, they've managed to make a heroku app using 'Buildpacks' where, you specify that the project has multiple builds ([heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi)), then specify the python based buildpack and the angular based (grunt) buildpack.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly special about this setup. Angular code is just static files, and can be served from whatever point you want; then the Ajax calls to the REST backend go to the endpoint you determined.